# sharing a link on facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook

can anyone please help me to understand how to share a link on facebook wall??

public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

```
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");///////
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);

            if (postId != null) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
                mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
                mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new Bundle(), "DELETE",
                                new WallPostDeleteListener(), null);
                    }
                });
                mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "No wall post made");
            }
        }
    }
```

i m getting a null value of post_id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following code

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "Test Photo");
parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\"My Test link\","
+"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"}");
facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution...."MY Test link" is shared but the message "test photo" is still not sharing ..... can anyone please help...

Answer (score 0):

For sharing of message just add one more param as:

```
params.putString("caption", "Test Photo");
```